# How to block certain site from specific app

Tags: android, firewall

I'm trying to block image sites from specific apps (for example:Facebook, WhatsApp, Google chrome) so I get only the text without any destructions.
I want to use block using regex  the url like this `*.png , images?/`
like I saw while sniffing the trffic in the chrome dev tool

[data:image  - ex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFX4t.jpg)

[images?/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nC3ae.jpg)

I want to write an app that block this kind of req but only from cetrin apps
Thank you!

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  Are you trying to block it in an app you're writing?  Or in another app?  The second would be off topic here, as you're not writing a program.  It would also not actually be possible on Android.

Comment: I want to write my own app, root could help?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @EyalElbaz even if you wrote an app it  wouldn't be possible.  YOu can block sites/IPs, you can't block filetypes.  Even if you proxied HTTP via a firewall, that would stop working if they just included their own HTTP engine in their APK, which isn't that uncommon.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a Chrome Extension to do that for you AFTER the site was loaded.

Comment: I want to make a mobile app so I could block block from any app